# Why do RF hybrid coupler opposite ports cancel?

Tags: rf, port, coupler

I am reading "Practical Radio Frequency Test & Measurement A Technician's Handbook." by Joseph J. Carr. The book states on page 36 (screenshots are attached) that "The one general rule to remember about hybrids is that opposite ports cancel." in RF Hybrid Coupler Section. Why do they cancel?

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

Answer (score 2):

> Why do they cancel?

A signal that is fed into port 1 (of the handbook's figure 2.20) travels around the coupler in both directions. That part of the signal that travels clockwise around the coupler reaches port 4 after a delay of 90\$^{\circ}\$. That part of the signal that travels counter-clockwise reaches port 4 after a delay of 450\$^{\circ}\$. These two signals are in phase, because 450 = 90 + 360.

Now consider the signal that travels clockwise from port 1 to port 2. It arrives with a delay of 360\$^{\circ}\$. The part of the signal that travels counter-clockwise arrives after a delay of 180\$^{\circ}\$. These two signals are 180\$^{\circ}\$ out of phase, so they cancel.

Similar considerations for other source-destination port pairs apply.

(I'm pretty sure the schematic symbol in fig 2.21 of your question does not match the physical layout in fig. 2.20. If the labels 4 and 2 in figure 2.21 were swapped, then that schematic symbol would match the physical layout in figure 2.20.)

(To add to the confusion, here is a completely different port numbering given in [Microwaves101.com](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/rat-race-couplers))

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The book explanation could be better.